# what actually happens when "ssh localhost" command is executed

Tags: linux, ssh

Today when reading article which describe how to install Hadoop, the author uses:
ssh localhost

what does the command mean?

Below is this article's location?
http://codesfusion.blogspot.com/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html?m=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a quick way of making sure that 'localhost' is added to the list of known hosts so that a script execution doesn't get interrupted by a question about trusting localhost's authenticity.

Answer (score 3):

The command means that a connection is conducted to the own machine, to the current user.

In general, that means a new login shell with (perhaps) new privileges, when the list of groups the user is member in has changed.

In the case given, this does not apply, as the user and groups are created beforehand.

Other reasons for `ssh localhost` may include

- the [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21926362/296974) addition to `.ssh/known_hosts`
- a clean environment

But be warned that after `ssh localhost` you are in a kind of "subshell" (it is not really a subshell, as we have a "thicker layer" in-between) so you have to `logout` / `exit` / `^D` twice.

For adding to `known_hosts` a mere `ssh localhost true` would have been enough; the connection is terminated immediately again.